# What are my options to measure oxygen concentration in a high temperature wood burner flue gas?

Tags: gas-sensor

I'd like to measure oxygen concentration in flue gas from my wood burner.

Lambda sensors are suitable but, even if relatively cheap, they need a control unit to keep working temperature and other parameters under control, and that increases the price significantly. I found the project [Lambda check](https://www.lambdacheck.de/preise.html) that is priced at around 300 euro. The sensor and control unit by themselves are about 180 euro on third party websites.

What are my other options to measure the oxygen concentration?

It has to be assumed soot will need to be periodically burned out and the operating temperature should exceed 500°C.

Comment: Could you measure the carbon monoxide instead? The chemical process in a continuous flame is simpler, so you could get away with a simpler sensoring.

Comment: Why do you need to control other parameters if all you want to do is measure the oxygen concentration? I can see why you would want to control other parameters if you want to keep the oxygen concentration between certain limits. Or is that what you really wanted to ask?

Comment: Maybe you can use an automotive O2 sensor- I believe some of them even have a heater- and build the interface electronics. They're just a Nernst cell.

Comment: Park your Fiat beside the chimney and run the wires through the combustion air duct. When you hear the idle speed change, you'll know something's happening.

Comment: Automotive lambda sensors aren't particularly hard to work with. I saw a project doing this 20 years ago with a 16F-series PIC, a couple of opamps and a few other discrete bits.

Comment: To be clear, is this a wood burner, or a wood gas reburner?  Are you trying to optimize the stoichiometry for a woodgas/oxygen mix?

Comment: @Janka well maybe, but that doesn't give me the excess air value, that I need to keep it according to specifications (10-13%)

Comment: @SolarMike yes I want to control burning, but that part is easy to do, once I know the oxygen in the flue gases. My question is really "what oxygen sensors are available for gases >500°C"

Comment: @SpehroPefhany not so easy, considering the temperature compensation, heater control, current source and votage detection, ...